# How can I test a custom IValueResolver in AutoMapper 10?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automapper, automapper-10

AutoMapper 10 has removed the public constructor from the ResolutionContext class (https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/10.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#the-resolutioncontext-no-longer-has-a-public-constructor).  I have previously been creating an instance to test a custom value resolver.  Since I can no longer create an instance, how can I continue to test my value resolver which depends on a resolution context?

Comment: You could find out where the resolution context is initialized in AutoMapper source code and use to your needs if it's possible. Alternativly, use reflection to manually create an instance.

Comment: Why not simply do what the docs suggest?

Comment: Perhaps because it is not obvious what the docs mean? At least when the current writing is "You can test the entire Map operation." I have no idea what that means and how it helps me to test my resolver. Did you find a solution for this?